# Flex and PHP with transaction support

Tags: php, actionscript-3, frameworks, transactions, flex4

I need to create an application that will use Flex on the client side and PHP on the server side. In my application I will need to have transactions opened for a long time (maybe 1, 2, 3 minutes). Can you give me any toughts on what PHP-FLEX fraework to use? I even found something like [AS3FlexDB](http://code.google.com/p/as3flexdb/) but it seem to not supporting transactions for a long time.

Any toughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library by your link is for connecting MySQL right from Flash client. As for me, your question isn't relevant to Flex but only related to PHP. Flex can produce client which can communicate with server using some protocol (XML or AMF using AMFPHP). But all the DB communication and transaction logic should be placed on a server (PHP) side. Flex client should be DB and transactions agnostic.

Comment: What if I want to keep a transaction open until a client fills some input data?

Comment: Server should wait for response from the client. But user can close the client before. So you should introduce some timeout for a client response.

Comment: Anyway, all the solution is on a server side. Client is just a client.